# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Window] has no method 'each'

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, window, each

I'm creating a jQuery plugin that interacts with Bootstrap, and I get the following error when I call the function on a jQuery element:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Window] has no method 'each'
```

This is the JavaScript in question:

```
!function ($) {
$.fn.alertAutoClose = function (interval) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    return $(this).each(function () {
      $(this).hide();
    });
  }, interval);
}(window.jQuery);
```

This is how the plugin is triggered:

```
$(".alert").alertAutoClose(1000);
```

This is the HTML on the page:

```
<div class="alert fade in">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
  <strong>Warning!</strong> Best check yo self, you're not looking too good.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of `setTimeout()`, `this` is `window`, not your object.  You would need to save the `this` reference and do something like this:

```
!function ($) {
$.fn.alertAutoClose = function (interval) {
     var self = this;
     setTimeout(function () {
       self.hide();
     }, interval);
     return this;
}(window.jQuery);
```

FYI, you can also accomplish the same thing like this:

```
!function ($) {
$.fn.alertAutoClose = function (interval) {
     this.delay(interval).hide(1);
     return this;
}(window.jQuery);
```

When you give `.hide()` a duration, it turns into an animation so it will work with `.delay()`.

Also, the `this` value inside a jQuery method is the jQuery object.  So, if you want to call a method that applies to all elements in the jQuery object, you can just call the method directly on `this`.  You don't have to turn it into a jQuery object (it already is one) and you don't have to use `.each()` because most jQuery methods (like `.hide()` already operate on all elements in the object.